# Eloquent: get AVG from all rows that have minimum timestamp

Tags: sql, eloquent

I want to get the User ID and it's average score from every minimum timestamp for each category. Here's the table structure

### Skill Table

```
id | user_id | category | score | timestamp**
0....10............a................11........12
1....10............a................10........9
2....10............b................12........10
3....10............c................11........8
4....11............a................8........9
5....11............b................9........10
6....11............c................10........8
7....11............c................15........14
```

I want to get the result like this:

```
user_id | AVG(score)
10........11 (average id: 1,2,3)
11........9 (average id: 4,5,6)
```

For now I use the looping query for every user

```
foreach ($userIds as $id){
    // in some case I need to get from only specified Ids not all of them

    foreach ($category as $cat) {

        // get the minimum timestamp's score for each category
        $rawCategory = Skill::where("user_id", $id)->where("timestamp", "<=", $start)->where("category",$cat->id)->orderBy("timestamp", "desc")->first();

        if($rawCategory){
            $skillCategory[$cat->cat_name] = $rawCategory->score;
        }
    }

    //get the average score
    $average = array_sum($skillCategory) / count($skillCategory);
}
```

I want to create better Eloquent query to get the data like this with good performance (< 60 sec). Have anyone faced a similar problem and solved it? If so, can you please give me the link. Thanks

Comment: So what is the problem? Simple query should simply run less than 60 seconds if the table is not that huge. Could you add some code and be a bit more specific?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Which column should I `GROUP BY`, since I need average score from the minimum timestamp of every category for all user specified?